# Parameter with ObjectDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a asp GridView in my page.I am using asp ObjectDataSource to bind data to my grid.I am calling a method from data layer to get the data.method have a parameter(userid).I want to pass the parameter from ObjectDataSource.user id is in session variable.How can i pass the parameter in  ObjectDataSource?

**code**

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="_allSitesDataMgr" runat="server" ConvertNullToDBNull="True"
    OldValuesParameterFormatString="{0}" SelectMethod="GetAllSitesByUser"  TypeName="PWRWebData.SiteCreation.SitesDataMgr"> 

</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a `<SelectParameters>` in your object data source

```
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:SessionParameter  Name="MyUserID" Type="Int32" SessionField="UserID" />
  </SelectParameters>
```

**Update:**

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="_allSitesDataMgr" runat="server" ConvertNullToDBNull="True"
    OldValuesParameterFormatString="{0}" SelectMethod="GetAllSitesByUser"  TypeName="PWRWebData.SiteCreation.SitesDataMgr"> 
<SelectParameters>
        <asp:SessionParameter  Name="MyUserID" Type="Int32" SessionField="UserID" />
      </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Comment: Then how i pass by userid from session to my method?